# Is there an alternative to .net's Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mono

Is there an alternative to .NET's [Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx) assembly? The [re-implementation in mono](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization) is far from being finished.

I don't care if the interface is different from the .NET one, I'm simple looking for a free (open-source) charting library for .net (4.0), which is usable in mono.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some time ago I was looking for a contemporary charting library and found [OxyPlot](https://oxyplot.github.io/), which works fine, has many backends and I was able to use it on Mono, on Raspberry Pi, simply downloaded using NuGet.

---

Old answer:

For such purpose I used [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/). It does work on Mono's winforms, it is open source and quite nice. There was no upgrades for long time, however you still have the source code. I recommend trying it.

I've just made a screenshot of their [sample project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20forms%20sample%20projects/5.1.2%20+%204.6.2/zedgraph_sample_projects_5.1.2.zip/download) using this library:
[image]

Comment: I get a literal Japanese pet medicine site from that link. You probably wanted https://oxyplot.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to search sites like http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com. Maybe you'll find. Whats up with http://googlechartnet.codeplex.com/ for instance?

Comment: That's an ASP.Net library, unfortunately, not a Windows.Forms one.

Comment: Sorry, did read too fast. What about http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/de-de/details.aspx?FamilyID=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C ?

Comment: @sprinter252: I'm looking for a library which will run in mono. I don't think the Microsoft implementation will run on mono (or on Linux for that matter)

Comment: @knittl: If it's pure .Net, it might.  But with a control library you might be right.  There are also going to be huge licensing/distribution issues because you can't simply run a windows installer on Linux, and you probably can't distribute anything off MS's site in anything but the original package.

Comment: @knittl: If you run the installer on client-side (development-system) and you package up your result there is a chance, that it'll run on mono too. I don't exactly know, how those libs dependent on direct Windows API so you have to try it, I guess. But thats the case anyway regardless the library you use.